# What will happen to evicted pods in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I just saw some of my pods got evicted by kubernetes. What will happen to them? just hanging around like that or I have to delete them manually?

Comment: Witnessing the same behavior, I have a pod that has been in `Evicted` state for 13 days now. Looks like evicted pods don't get removed (or maybe it is just a bug).

Comment: podgc controller will reclaim those Failed/Succeeded pods when a configurable threshold reached.

Comment: My Pods are evicted and there is a total of 40. 
So will I be charged per month for those evicted pods too?

Comment: Bunch of containers are evicted but I Still have 2 containers running as expected. Failed ones were because of low resource(`DiskPressure`) which can be found using `kubectl describe pods my-pod-name --namespace prod`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

A quick workaround I use, is to delete all evicted pods manually after an incident. You can use this command:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.status.reason!=null) | select(.status.reason | contains("Evicted")) | "kubectl delete pods \(.metadata.name) -n \(.metadata.namespace)"' | xargs -n 1 bash -c
```

Comment: Checkout this one too https://gist.github.com/psxvoid/71492191b7cb06260036c90ab30cc9a0

Comment: You must have a typo, `-a` argument is invalid.

Comment: This (and similar answers) do not answer the OP question "What will happen to them [if you don't do anything]?"

Comment: To run this on a schedule, you can set up a k8s cronjob, just follow the easy doc here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: Alternative more readable option to delete within a single namespace:
`kubectl get pod -n mynamespace | grep Evicted | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod -n mynamespace`

Answer (score 117):

To delete pods in Failed state in namespace `default`

```sh
kubectl -n default delete pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed
```

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't show any when `status.phase=Evicted`. I managed to do this by `kubectl -n default delete pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running`. But be careful, this would delete everything

Comment: I guess it can be useful to run `kubectl -n default get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed` at first.

Comment: It does get rid of the `Evicted` pods for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm for my Evicted pods on EKS v1.16.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me in latest GCP k8s

Comment: @n3o Evicted is not a Pod phase
refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase

Comment: "=Failed" worked great on 150 evicted pods for me.  This on Kubernetes v1.20.8

Answer (score 39):

Evicted pods should be manually deleted. You can use following command to delete all pods in `Error` state.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed' -o json | kubectl delete -f -
```

Answer (score 33):

To answer the original question: the evicted pods will hang around until the number of them reaches the `terminated-pod-gc-threshold` limit (it's an option of [kube-controller-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8cc91944e0555af82f86cc7f21fb638be60665fd/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager.md) and is equal to 12500 by default), it's by design behavior of Kubernetes (also the same approach is used and documented for Jobs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup). Keeping the evicted pods pods around allows you to view the logs of those pods to check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic output.

Answer (score 32):

Depending on if a soft or hard [eviction threshold](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#eviction-thresholds) that has been met, the Containers in the Pod will be terminated with or without grace period, the `PodPhase` will be marked as `Failed` and the Pod deleted. If your Application runs as part of e.g. a Deployment, there will be another Pod created and scheduled by Kubernetes - probably on another Node not exceeding its eviction thresholds.

Be aware that eviction does not necessarily have to be caused by thresholds but can also be invoked via `kubectl drain` to [empty a node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) or manually via the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#the-eviction-api).

Comment: yeah, my pod is from a deployment, and i do see another pod running on another node, but those previous evicted pods are also there

Comment: How do you determine that are they "also there"? Which command exactly shows that to you?

Comment: just `kubectl get pods -n mynamespace`

Comment: In which state? What does `kubectl describe pod <pod>` say?

Comment: Not OP but I have this issue.  `kubectl describe `says "Status:  Failed
Reason:  Evicted
Message: Pod The node was low on resource: [MemoryPressure]."

Answer (score 16):

The bellow command delete all failed pods from all namespaces

```
kubectl get pods -A | grep Evicted | awk '{print $2 " -n " $1}' | xargs -n 3 kubectl delete pod
```

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 13):

One more bash command to delete evicted pods

```
kubectl get pods | grep Evicted | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod
```

Answer (score 12):

Just in the case someone wants to automatically delete all evicted pods for all namespaces:

- Powershell

```
    Foreach( $x in (kubectl get po --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase=Failed --no-headers -o custom-columns=:metadata.name)) {kubectl delete po $x --all-namespaces }
```

- Bash

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase=Failed --no-headers -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | xargs kubectl delete po --all-namespaces
```

Comment: in case it helps, you can set this to run on a schedule as a k8s cronjob, by following the easy doc here: kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs

Comment: I love you for adding the Pwsh version of the command. Running Windows 10 and I dont have Bash.

Answer (score 10):

`Kube-controller-manager` exists by default with a working K8s installation.  It appears that the default is a max of 12500 terminated pods before GC kicks in.

Directly from the K8s documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/#kube-controller-manager

> --terminated-pod-gc-threshold int32     Default: 12500 
>   Number of terminated pods that can exist before the terminated pod garbage collector starts deleting terminated pods. If <= 0, the terminated pod garbage collector is disabled.

Comment: I have the kube-controller-manager pods on my master nodes. But how should I modify this flag? If I want to use `kubectl edit pod kube-controller-manager-<master_name> -n kube-system` it gives me `pod is invalid` error after saving the config file.

Comment: for us, we cannot edit the config for kube-controller-manager as we are on AKS. so we set up a quick cronjob for cleanup: kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs

Answer (score 7):

In case you have pods with a `Completed` status that you want to keep around:

```sh
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed' -o json | kubectl delete -f -
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way still with `awk`.

To prevent any human error that could make me crazy (deleting desirable pods), I check before the result of the `get pods` command :

```
kubectl -n my-ns get pods --no-headers --field-selector=status.phase=Failed
```

If that looks good, here we go :

```
kubectl -n my-ns get pods --no-headers --field-selector=status.phase=Failed | \
awk '{system("kubectl -n my-ns delete pods " $1)}'
```

Same thing with pods of all namespaces.

Check :

```
kubectl get -A pods --no-headers --field-selector=status.phase=Failed
```

Delete :

```
kubectl get -A pods --no-headers --field-selector status.phase=Failed | \
awk '{system("kubectl -n " $1 " delete pod " $2 )}'
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenShift equivalent of Kalvin's command to delete all 'Evicted' pods:

```
eval "$(oc get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.status.phase == "Failed" and .status.reason == "Evicted") | "oc delete pod --namespace " + .metadata.namespace + " " + .metadata.name')"
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete all the `Evicted` pods by force, you can try this one-line command:

```
$ kubectl get pod -A | sed -nr '/Evicted/s/(^\S+)\s+(\S+).*/kubectl -n \1 delete pod \2 --force --grace-period=0/e'
```

Tips: use the `p` modifier of `s` command of `sed` instead of `e` will just print the real command to do the deletion job:

```
$ kubectl get pod -A | sed -nr '/Evicted/s/(^\S+)\s+(\S+).*/kubectl -n \1 delete pod \2 --force --grace-period=0/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

below command will get all evicted pods from the default namespace and delete them

`kubectl get pods | grep Evicted | awk '{print$1}' | xargs -I {} kubectl delete pods/{}`

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged, as it will not help like an answer with explained context that helps the community in long run.

Answer (score 1):

### I found this to be the fastest way to delete evicted pods

```bash
kubectl delete pod -A --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed'
```

*(Only matters when you have **A LOT** of them accumulated)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 'official' guide for how to hard code the threshold(if you do not want to see too many evicted pods): [kube-controll-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/)

But a known problem is how to have kube-controll-manager installed...

Comment: Please advise on how the mentioned installation may be achieved, if it is troublesome.

Comment: I do not know the answer either that is why I mentioned it. And OP did not mention the system he using and I do not know if he would have the same issue. BTW, downvote is SUPER NICE.

Comment: You would I think have done better adding your idea as a comment since it doesn't fully answer the question (which is why I downvoted it - sorry but it happens to us all, including me just now).

Comment: check all the other answers above, OP asked what happened and how many of them did answer that and how many of them provide a way to delete the eviction pod?

Answer (score 0):

When we have too many evicted pods in our cluster, this can lead to network load as each pod, even though it is evicted is connected to the network and in case of a cloud Kubernetes cluster, will have blocked an IP address, which can lead to exhaustion of IP addresses too if you have a fixed pool of IP addresses for your cluster.

Also, when we have too many pods in Evicted status, it becomes difficult to monitor the pods by running the kubectl get pod command as you will see too many evicted pods, which can be a bit confusing at times.

To delete and evicted pod run the following command

```
kubectl delete pod <podname> -n <namespace>
```

what if you have many evicted pods

```
kubectl get pod -n <namespace> | grep Evicted | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had too many pods with evicted and completed status and I have used this 2 commands to delete all of them.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.status.reason!=null) | select(.status.reason | contains("Evicted")) | "kubectl delete pods \(.metadata.name) -n \(.metadata.namespace)"' | xargs -n 1 bash -c 
kubectl delete pods --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded --all-namespaces
```